# What is the best approach to find elements in collection that fullfill scenario

Tags: design, architecture, algorithms, .net

I have a collection of people. Each person have rank (A, B, C, D where A highest and D lowest) and set of skills (SkillA, SkillB, SkillC, SkillD) defined.
I also have a set of requirements - for example:
- 1 person with rank A
- 1 person with rank B and SkillA
- 3 persons with rank C and SkillA and SkillC
etc.

I'm looking for a best approach to check if there is any combination of persons in collection that will fulfill the set requirements. One person can't be used for two requirements.

I'm using .NET and at the moment I'm trying to build solve that with LINQ queries, but in the meantime I'm interested if there is other way to approach this.

Comment: I suspect there is an algorithm for this. Right now the question is not clear. I suggest you clean up the problem statement and add some sample data and output.  I assume a person can have more than 1 skill?  Is the rank per skill?  Can you sub a higher rank if necessary?

Comment: Sounds like a complicated Knapsack problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you have pegs and slots. Your problem is that some pegs might fit in more than one slot, but only one choice will allow you to fill all the slots.

I would go with a recursive algorithm for a depth first search. Which you could implement in Linq, but its prob easier to type it out 'long hand' as it were

```
Fill(List<slot> slots, List<peg> pegs, string fittedPegs)
{
   if(slots.Count == 0)
   {
        return fittedPegs;//yay we filled them all!
   }
   foreach(var peg in pegs.where(p=>p.Fits(slots[0]))
   {
        fittedPegs += "," + peg.id;
        var r = Fill(slots.Skip(1),pegs.Where(p=>p!=peg), fittedPegs);
        if(r != null) {return r;}
   }
   return null; //cant fit all the pegs :(
}
```

* not tested

Comment: Just be sure to make the problem complex enough that the universe doesn't end too soon! (Towers of Hanoi)

Comment: I went with your suggestion and coded this way, almost without LINQ query and I like this approach. Not to much code and readable. Thank you Ewan.